# Convert Serial.read() into a usable integer

Tags: arduino, integer

When I send the number "5" to the Arduino through the serial monitor then `Serial.read()` will output "53" because 53 is the ASCII value for "5".

What I need to do is to convert the "53" (or any other number that `Serial.read()` gives) to a normal integer so when I send "5" to the Arduino then the Arduino will see it as "5" not "53".

Also I cannot use `Serial.parseInt()` because it has a 1 second delay, but I need to receive the number instantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delay in `parseInt()` is probably due to your serial timeout.

`parseInt()` *might* still work for you if you can send a non-numeric character immediately after, as is discussed in [this discussion](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=99336.0) on the Arduino site.

Alternatively, you could shorten the timeout radically as discussed here:

> Michael Margolis' "Arduino Cookbook" (2nd edition, page 113) to the rescue!
>
> It turns out that the Serial class (which extends the Stream class) uses the Stream.setTimeout() function. The default value for the timeout is 1000 (one second). I just set it to something smaller, like 50 ms, and the sketch is nice and zippy. Here's the complete example sketch. Turn off line endings in the serial monitor...

Comment: Thanks. I used `Serial.setTimeout(50)`, it worked perfectly.